# Defining map projection of Eastern part of Ukraine

Tags: coordinate-system, ukraine

I have a map of the Eastern part of Ukraine, which was apparently used in the ceasefire negotiations to define the borderline between the conflicting sides.

The full map: https://informnapalm.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/karta-polnayacc.jpg

The map is quite detailed but I could not find the type of projection it uses.
Moreover, it is difficult (though possible) to see the exact numbers.

However, there are some numbers.

- Coordinate `X` varies from `7288000` to `7612000`
- Coordinate `Y` varies from `6192000` to `6608000`
- The gap between meridians and parallels is equal to `4000` map units.

Coordinates `X` and `Y` should roughly correspond to

- Longitude `47.12°N` - `49.65°N`
- Latitude `36.15°E` - `40.19°E`

in WGS84 respectively (I used Google Maps).

The middle of the map is a city called [Debaltseve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debaltseve) located at `48.33°N` and `38.36°E`.

Although the headers are in Russian, the names of the places are in Ukrainian.

Thus, I thought that it is likely to be one of the Ukrainian projection systems. I tried to use the [epsg.io](http://epsg.io/) website and play with the common Ukrainian projection systems it stores but every time I tried to transform the WGS84 coordinates into one of the Ukrainian projection systems, I got an error.

Could you suggest me what kind of projection system the map might use?

Comment: Your map isn't in degrees (Long/Lat), it's probably in metres (Eastings and Northings).

Comment: Did you consider http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-37n/

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It is not the projection system. But I went in a similar direction and played with the Pulkovo projection, which is widely used in the post-Soviet space. It seems that Pulkovo1995 GK Time Zone 7 matches very well after I downsized the y-coordinate by 1'000'000 units. Most likely, I made a mistake interpreting the numbers from the image. 5 and 6 look similar on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [@nmtoken](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/27874/nmtoken) suggested my map measures coordinates not in degrees but in meters and therefore a sort of UTM projection.

WGS 84 / UTM zone 37N [EPSG:32637](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-37n/) did not work. The closest projection I was able to get was Pulkovo1995 / Gauss-Kruger Zone 7 [EPSG:20007](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/20007/).

[image: Pulkovo1995, GK Zone 7. The yellow highlighted regions indicate the location the raster should project on]

The X-coordinates seem to match but Y-coordinates are biased almost by `1'000'000` units.

I had another look at the raster file and realized that it is difficult to differentiate between the values 5 and 6. I used another Y-coordinates: `5192000` and `5508000`.

[image: Adjusted coordinates georeference of the raster. Pulkovo1995 GK Zone 7]

Besides the almost perfect match, the image is not squizzed indicating a perfect match.